# Change default viewer in eclipse/texlipse

Tags: eclipse, pdf-reader

Using Eclipse + Texlipse (LaTeX plugin) on Ubuntu 11.04 -- though it should apply to other OSs too.

In the project explorer, double clicking on a PDF file will open it with the "System Editor" or "Default Editor". In practise, if I double click a PDF it gets opened by Adobe Reader, while my default PDF reader is different (Okular in my case).

Where does Eclipse get the information about the default editor/viewer?

I'm aware there is a "Preview Document" button in Texlipse that can be customised to use any viewer, but I'm just trying to understand how Eclipse works.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question.  And it has a great answer.

By default Texlipse intrusively installs a plug-in called PDF4Eclipse. You're *supposed* to be able to [configure the default editor via the File Associations dialog](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-13.htm), but in case you're fed up of the internal pdf viewer and never want to use it, you can just remove it instead.

To remove it, go **Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details**

[image: inst details]

There you will see a list of items,

[image: pdf]

Pick PDF4Eclipse from the list, and choose **Uninstall** at the bottom.

I already did it in this screenshot, which is why I had to ink in PDF4Eclipse!

Answer (score -1):

Go to `Window > Preferences > Texlipse > Viewer Settings`. Now, click `New` and create a new viewer configuration with the correct path to your preferred PDF viewer.

You can find elaborated details here: http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/build.html

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I refer to. I know about the possibility of opening the file with that method. However, I was looking for a solution to change what the "System editor" points to, whether that be a PDF viewer or anything else. Apologies if the question wasn't clear.